# RHEL won't update correctly a package for security

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel7, redhat-ubi

What does that error even mean?
I have tzdata package. I run yum update --security and I get this:

```
[dada@dada-dada-dispatcher aem]# yum update --security
Failed to set locale, defaulting to C
Loaded plugins: search-disabled-repos
 --> tzdata-2022f-1.el7.noarch from rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms removed (updateinfo)
 --> tzdata-2022e-1.el7.noarch from @rhui-rhel-7-server-rhui-rpms removed (updateinfo)
No packages needed for security; 1 packages available
Resolving Dependencies
```

No need to update for security, but I have a package available?